# outputing 32 bit pngs to make a video

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

I have a rotating 3d image on a transparent background psd. How do I render/output it in Photoshop CC to keep the transparent background as a set of 32bit pngs to create a video?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue you're having correctly, exporting PNGs should be fairly simple.

1. Access the Render Video dialogue by selecting **File -> Export ->
   Render Video...**
2. Choose a name for your files and select the folder location where you'd like the rendered files to go.
3. Click the drop-down below the Location section, and make sure **Photoshop Image Sequence** is selected
4. Select the format drop-down and **select PNG** and adjust settings as needed.
5. Specify the range of frames you want to export.
6. **Click on the Alpha Channel drop-down** and choose **Straight - Unmatted** *(This will give you your transparent background)*
7. **Click Render**

Navigate to the folder location you chose, and your PNG sequence should be there.

Hope that helps!